# Passing opencv read image to dll c++ function

Tags: python, c++, opencv, dll, ctypes

I am having problems of reading pixel info from c++ function, I can read all other argument so I am sure that my connection are working.
My python code are as follows

```
real_img = cv2.imread("215107.jpg", 0)
n=real_image.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8))
hllDll=WinDLL(name)
hllDll.transform(n,ctypes.c_int(myimage.shape[0]), ctypes.c_int(myimage.shape[1]), ctypes.c_int(angle))
```

I have also tried

```
src1 = real_image.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_char_p)
hllDll.transform(src1,ctypes.c_int(myimage.shape[0]), ctypes.c_int(myimage.shape[1]), ctypes.c_int(angle))
```

and

```
src2=ctypes.c_void_p(real_img.ctypes.data)
hllDll.transform(src2,ctypes.c_int(myimage.shape[0]), ctypes.c_int(myimage.shape[1]), ctypes.c_int(angle))
```

but failed
and my c++ function is as follows:

```
unsigned int transform(int** a, int row,int col, int ang){
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
...}
```

When I try to read from a, they all just give me same huge numbers like

```
1212121212121212
1212121212121212
1413131211111010
1012141311101113
```

while they should be 18 for first 5 numbers if I access through python, I am so confused what made this happen

Edit:
I also tried
cout << a[i][1] << endl;
But `OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` returned

Comment: What is the different between `real_img`, `real_image` and `myimage`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, they are the same thing. I forgot to change them here. But it does not affect the code.@Rotem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array of type `np.uint8`, the equivalent C pointer is `unsigned char*`.

Replace `int** a` with `unsigned char* a`.

---

For testing, you may fill the 4 first elements of `real_image`:

```
real_image[0, 0] = 1
real_image[0, 1] = 2
real_image[0, 2] = 3
real_image[0, 3] = 4

hllDll.transform(n,ctypes.c_int(real_image.shape[0]), ctypes.c_int(real_image.shape[1]), ctypes.c_int(angle))
```

---

Your C code may look as follows:

```
unsigned int transform(unsigned char* a, int row, int col, int ang){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << (int)a[i] << endl; // add [0] to access the first row
    }
}
```

The pointer `unsigned char* a` is not a pointer to two dimensional array, but a pointer to one dimensional array (in row major format).

---

For passing two dimensional NumPy array to C, you better add **stride** argument to your C function.
The stride is the number of bytes to step between two sequential rows.

---

For testing, you may fill the 4 first element of each row:

```
real_image[0, 0] = 1
real_image[1, 0] = 2
real_image[2, 0] = 3
real_image[3, 0] = 4
```

---

Your C code may look as follows:

```
unsigned int transform(unsigned char* a, int row, int col, int stride, int ang){
    //Print the first element of each one of the first 4 rows
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << (int)a[i*stride] << endl;
    }
}
```

Note the new `stride` argument, and `a[i*stride]`.

---

Executing `transform` from Python:

```
hllDll.transform(n,ctypes.c_int(real_image.shape[0]), ctypes.c_int(real_image.shape[1]), ctypes.c_int(real_image.strides[0]), ctypes.c_int(angle))
```

---

Note:

- It is most likely that `col` = `stride`, but it's not always the case.

Answer (score -1):

You are printing the pointers for each rows. If you want to print elements of the first row, you should do like this:

```
unsigned int transform(int** a, int row,int col, int ang){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << a[0][i] << endl; // add [0] to access the first row
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did try it, but whenever I do so, it gives me access error, hllDll.transform(n,ctypes.c_int(myimage.shape[0]), ctypes.c_int(myimage.shape[1]), ctypes.c_int(angle))
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: that's not the solution. this isn't an array of arrays. the data of a numpy `array` is just linear memory.