# Cython Passing an raw image from python to external C++ library

Tags: python, c++, image, cython

What I'm trying to do is load a png using the python program, pass the raw binary to the C++ to modify and return it back to the python program. Im using Cython as a way to access the C++ .dll file right now, however I'm having an issue passing the image along.

The code successfully passed and returned strings and int to and from C++ but I cant seem to able to pass the full image file (raw). I tried to put the files back together again on the C++ side but it doesnt seem to work, only like the first few bytes are passed along and gets written down on the C++ side. This is what I got from the terminal from the C++ side: `�PNG` and this is what it returned to the python script`\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n`

From my understanding I'm pretty sure the issue is the Cython ctype conversion or the C++ param side. Im not sure am I using the `unsigned char*` right or not but from my understand C++ dont have a byte type and an unsigned char should work? If unsigned char* is not the same as byte what should I put in the param for the C++ method?

Python:

```
image = ""
# open the image
with open("image.png", "rb") as s:
    image = s.read()

# set the return type
lib.input.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

# call the c++ method
reply = lib.input(image)

# print out the reply
print(f'this is the reply {reply}')
```

C++

```
unsigned char* input(unsigned char* input)
{
   // print the input
   std::cout << input << std::endl;
   return input;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a problem but `char*` is a bad way to pass strings, because it can't cope with strings containing `\0`

Comment: **1.** You are passing the PNG file content, instead of passing the image raw data. You may use OpenCV for reading the raw BGR data into NumPy array: `image = cv2.imread("image.png")`. **2.** Passing a pointer to `unsigned char*` is not enough, you better also pass `int cols`, `int rows` and also `int stride`. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68164156/passing-opencv-read-image-to-dll-c-function). **3.** Returning a pointer to `unsigned char*` is not the way to pass the output from C++ to Python. You better use `void input(const unsigned char* input ... unsigned char* output)`.

Comment: As @Rotem said, you are actually passing a *"PNG-encoded"* image, not a *"raw"* image. A *"raw"* image generally means either a) an image with **no** header or metadata where the first byte corresponds to the first pixel or b) a manufacturer-specific image from a camera manufacturer like Canon `.CR2` files, Nikon `.NEF` files, Sony `.ARW` files or Adobe `.DNG` files.